# ModelMap adds attribute in the same place of another one

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a ModelMap and I add all what I need, but in one case, when I add a `List` it replace another element in the model map.

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> hashAlteradosAnalitica =
                CalculoValoresAlterados.obtieneAlterados(listaAnaliticaPaciente.get(0), paciente);
 model.addAttribute("hashAlteradosVarAnalitica", hashAlteradosAnalitica);

//Do some stuff..

 HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> hashAlteradosCuestionariosNoQoL =
                CalculoValoresAlterados.obtieneAlteradosCuestionario(listaCuestionariosNoQoL, paciente,
                    rangocuestionariosService);
            model.addAttribute("hashAlteradosCuestionariosNoQoL", hashAlteradosCuestionariosNoQoL);

//Do some stuff...

HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> hashAlteradosCuestionariosQol =
                CalculoValoresAlterados.obtieneAlteradoCuestionarioCalidad(listaCuestionarioQol, paciente,
                    rangocuestionariosService);
            model.addAttribute("hashAlteradosCuestionariosQol", hashAlteradosCuestionariosQol);

//Do some stuff...

HashMap<String, Object> alterado = hashAlteradosCumplimiento.get(cumplimiento.getIdcumplimiento());
            model.addAttribute("hashResultadoCumplimiento", alterado);

//Do some stuff...

model.addAttribute("color_analitica", color_analitica);
model.addAttribute("color_calidad", color_calidad);
model.addAttribute("color_nocalidad", color_nocalidad);
model.addAttribute("color_cumplimiento", color_cumplimiento);
model.addAttribute("ultimaAnalitica", ultimaAnalitica);
model.addAttribute("listaAnaliticaPaciente", listaAnaliticaPaciente);
model.addAttribute("listaCuestionarioResultado", listaCuestionarioResultado);
model.addAttribute("listaCuestionariosNoQoL", listaCuestionariosNoQoL);
model.addAttribute("listaCuestionarioQol", listaCuestionarioQol);
model.addAttribute("cumplimiento", cumplimiento);
model.addAttribute("listaCumplimiento", listaCumplimiento);

return model;
```

When I add `model.addAttribute("listaCuestionarioQol", listaCuestionarioQol);` it replaces the 9th positon on `modelMap` Hash which is the same with `hashAlteradosVarAnalitica` and the size is incremented by 1.

Edit.

This always do the same, when I add `listaCuestionariosNoQoL`

> [null, *some data*, null,
>   listaCuestionariosNoQoL=[*some data*], listaNotasclinicas=[*some data*],
>   usuario=*some data*, null, urlDestino=*someUrl*,
>   listaAnaliticaPaciente=[*some data*],
>   **hashAlteradosVarAnalitica={1={valor=true, rango=0,5, incluyen=4,1}, 2={valor=false, rango=0,50, incluyen=4,1}, 3={valor=true, rango=3,5,
>   incluyen=4,4}, 4={valor=true, rango=14,17, incluyen=4,4}}**,
>   listaPatologiasPaciente=[*some data*], null, null,
>   listaCuestionarioResultado=[*some data*],
>   color_nocalidad=color_negativo,
>   hashAlteradosCuestionariosNoQoL={4={valor=true, rango=0,4,
>   incluyen=4,4}, 7={valor=true, rango=0,3, incluyen=4,4}},
>   hashResultadoCumplimiento={valor=false, rango=90,100, incluyen=1,4},
>   color_analitica=color_negativo, null, null, null, null,
>   color_cumplimiento=color_positivo, null, urlOrigen=*someUrl*,
>   ultimaAnalitica=*some data*, null, color_calidad=color_negativo, null,
>   hashAlteradosCuestionariosQol={1={valor=true, rango=50,252,
>   incluyen=1,4}}, null, null]

And in the next step, when I add `listaCuestionarioQol` this is the result, `hashAlteradosVarAnalitica` dissapear and I want to keep it...

> [null, paciente=.*some data*, null, listaCuestionariosNoQoL=[*some
>   data*], listaNotasclinicas=[*some data*], usuario=*some data*, null,
>   urlDestino=*someUrl*, listaAnaliticaPaciente=[*some data*],
>   **listaCuestionarioQol=[*some data*]**, listaPatologiasPaciente=[*some
>   data*], null, null, listaCuestionarioResultado=[*some data*],
>   color_nocalidad=color_negativo,
>   hashAlteradosCuestionariosNoQoL={4={valor=true, rango=0,4,
>   incluyen=4,4}, 7={valor=true, rango=0,3, incluyen=4,4}},
>   hashResultadoCumplimiento={valor=false, rango=90,100, incluyen=1,4},
>   color_analitica=color_negativo, null, null, null, null,
>   color_cumplimiento=color_positivo, null, urlOrigen=*someUrl*,
>   ultimaAnalitica=*some data*, null, color_calidad=color_negativo, null,
>   hashAlteradosCuestionariosQol={1={valor=true, rango=50,252,
>   incluyen=1,4}}, null, null]

Comment: Let me get is straight: you are inserting an `Attribute` with the same key in your `ModelMap` and it replaces the element (as expectedI guess) BUT also increases the size by 1?

Comment: @Eypros No, I insert an Attribute but I don't whant to replace the another in the same key, for example I want to insert listaCuestionarioQol in place 2 (or another who is free), not in the 9 where is hashAlteradosVarAnalitica

Comment: Quite confusing, what do this two objects have in common:
* `listaCuestionarioQol`
* `hashAlteradosAnalitica` ?
How do they look like?

Comment: @tmarwen they are completly different the first its a `List` of entities (Cuestionarios) and the second is a has who only have Strings and ids to locate items in `listaAnaliticaPaciente`

Comment: Please add the object body descriptions to your main thread, and post in the whole request handler method body.

Comment: `ModelMap` is a `Map` it does not specify the specific location of each element. When you insert an element it might change the order of the others. That's expected or at least not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but I resolved this by changin this:

Originally I have:

```
 model.addAttribute("hashAlteradosVarAnalitica", hashAlteradosAnalitica);
```

And change to

```
 model.addAttribute("hashAlteradosAnalitica", hashAlteradosAnalitica);
```

And works, anyone knows why?